# apply a map function on pyspark RDD

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have got a rdd by reading a mongodb collection and Now i want to change some value and update/load that data back to same or other collections.

```
mr1 = sc.mongoRDD('mongodb://localhost:27017/test_database.test2')
type(mr1)   #<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>
mr1.collect()
#[{u'_id': ObjectId('58089490d7531cd8b071f48c'), u'name': u'ravi', u'sal': u'2000'}, {u'_id': ObjectId('58089491d7531cd8b071f48d'), u'name': u'ravi', u'sal': u'3000'}]
#I want to change the name 'ravi' to 'Satya'
mr2 = mr1.map( lambda x: x['name'].replace('ravi','SATYA'))
#o/p: [u'SATYA', u'SATYA']  ##not all values
#Expected: [{u'_id': ObjectId('58089490d7531cd8b071f48c'), u'name': u'SATYA', u'sal': u'2000'}, {u'_id': ObjectId('58089491d7531cd8b071f48d'), u'name': u'SATYA', u'sal': u'3000'}]
```

Please help, how to apply a map function here to get back the same rdd mr1 with names replaced.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def replace(x, key, fr, to):
    d = x.copy()
    if key in d:
        d[key] = d[key].replace('ravi','SATYA')
    return d

mr1.map(lambda x: replace(x, 'name', 'ravi','SATYA'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Got it worked-

```
def rep(x):
    if x['name'] == 'ravi':
      x['name']='SATYA'
    return x
mr2 = mr1.map(lambda x: rep(x))
```